# Behavior of the solution to the inviscid Burgers' equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the inviscid Burgers' equation $u_t+uu_x=0$ with the initial condition $$u_0=\begin{cases}
0, & x<0\\
x, & 0\leq x \leq 1\\
1, & x>1 
\end{cases}$$

I tried to implement numerical method to solve this and I got this solution:[image]

Can somebody pls explain the behavior of this solution? I got the following characteristics:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of characteristics gives the solution $u = u_0(x-ut)$, where $u_0$ is the initial data. In the present case, we have

- $u=0$ if $x-0\cdot t\leq 0$;
- $u=1$ if $x-1\cdot t\geq 1$;
- $u=x-ut$ i.e. $u=x/(1+t)$ otherwise;

so that
$$
u(x,t) = \left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
&0 & & \text{if}\quad x \leq 0 ,\\
&\tfrac{x}{1+t} & & \text{if}\quad 0 \leq x \leq 1+ t ,\\
&1 & & \text{if}\quad 1+ t \leq x .
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
The previous analysis seems consistent with the numerical results in OP, up to the right boundary $x=3$ where a Dirichlet boundary condition may have been implemented. An outflow boundary condition would be more appropriate.